# What is the difference between swashbuckle.aspnetcore and swashbuckle packages?

Tags: .net-core

When I install swashbuckle for a .net core app, I see two options `swashbuckle.aspnetcore` and `swashbuckle`.

Can someone please tell me the differences between these two packages?

Comment: thanks @Cutwow for edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I figured in last 30 minutes out I guess, latter is specifically for .net core applications only.
Just in case someone need.